# Unitary CFT and Kac determinant

Tags: hilbert-space, conformal-field-theory, unitarity

I am currently reading [the BPZ paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(84)90052-X), and trying to understand the nature of Minimal models.
We compute the Kac determinant, and it is claimed that it must be positive for the theory to be a Unitary CFT.
Now, suppose that we choose a basis(for the vector space at some level $N$ of the degenerate conformal family) s.t the Gram matrix is diagonal, and each matrix element is simply the norm of that state. 
Hence, if we have even number of negative eigenvalues, even then the Kac determinant is positive.
Hence, there must be some additional condition which forbids this.

Summary - How can we show that the Kac determinant being positive implies that it is a Unitary CFT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, positivity of the Kac determinant is a necessary condition, but it is not sufficient. The full argument is in the Big Yellow Book by di Francesco et al. Positivity of the Kac determinant plays a crucial role: the idea is to start from a region in parameters (central charge, conformal dimension) where all eigenvalues are manifestly positive, and to keep track of sign changes as parameters vary.